# Using PHP to get Facebook friends statuses?

Tags: php, facebook, get, status

That's my first post here on SO.

I'm using PHP to get Facebook friends statuses. In particular, I've tried to retrieve all public statuses from one of my facebook friends, but it happens only the first 100 statuses. I need to get all the statuses and to write them in a text file. this is the code I'm using, patched up from many answers I read here on SO.

```
$i=0;
$result = $facebook->api('/my_friend_ID/statuses/',
array('access_token' => $facebook->access_token,'limit'=>100,));
```

//'offset'=>50,used before limit, it push the limits forward by 50, it doesn't go    beyond it
   //'since'=>2010, I read on SO there was even this field, but I can't make it work.

```
foreach($result['data'] as $post)
{
    echo $i . '<br>';
    echo $post['id'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['from']['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['from']['id'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['message'] . '<br>';
    echo '*---------------------------------------------------*' . '<br>';
    $i++;
    $write_file = fopen("esempio.txt","a");
    $message = $post['message'] . '<br>';
    fwrite($write_file,$message);
    fclose($write_file);

}
```

so, to be clearer, how to get all friends statuses (old and new) in a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use paging https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/

```
$the_statuses = array();

$your_statuses = $facebook->api("/my_friend_ID/statuses/");

while ($your_statuses['data'])
{
    $the_statuses = array_merge( $the_statuses, $your_statuses['data'] );

    $paging = $your_statuses['paging'];
    $next = $paging['next'];

    $query = parse_url($next, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($query, $par);

    $your_statuses = $facebook->api(
            "/my_friend_ID/statuses/", 'GET', array(
            'limit' => $par['limit'],
            'until'  => $par['until'] ));
}
```

Then you can do the loop through all statuses

```
foreach($the_statuses['data'] as $post)
{
    echo $i . '<br>';
    echo $post['id'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['from']['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['from']['id'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['name'] . '<br>';
    echo $post['message'] . '<br>';
    echo '*---------------------------------------------------*' . '<br>';
    $i++;
    $write_file = fopen("esempio.txt","a");
    $message = $post['message'] . '<br>';
    fwrite($write_file,$message);
    fclose($write_file);

}
```

Comment: Thank you phwd.I tried, but it doesn't work. I changed my_friend_ID with my friends actual ID, but it doesn't show any result. where do I get wrong?